# How to create local network in virtualbox between Ubuntu server

Tags: linux, virtualbox, ip

I created a Ubuntu server on virtualbox that Ubuntu server install with minimal virtual machine.
I created the three linked clone and I have internal network between them. I removed 70-persistent-net.rules.
I see this output when I run  ifconfig:

```
eth0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 08:00:27:e6:72:8a
     inet6 addr:fe80::a00:27ff:fee6:728a/64 Scop:Link
     .
     .
     .
```

I cannot see IPv4 address. I need an IPv4 address. How do I get this?

Comment: Which runlevel you are using?

Comment: i am newbie,what is runlevel?

Comment: In the command prompt just type `runlevel` and press Enter. It will show some number tell me that number.

Comment: In VirtualBox goto Settings > Network in that check "Attached to" in this you selected NAT or Bridged Adapter?

Comment: i selected internal network

Comment: Select Bridged Adapter and start the machine. It will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `VirtualBox` goto [image] > [image] in that check "Attached to" and select Bridged Adapter. It will work. like this.

[image]